# Setting FromAddress for MassEmailMessage

Tags: apex, email, batch, massemailmessage

Is there a way to set the From Address when sending MassEmailMessage via a batch job? Ideally I want to use OrgWideEmailAddress but I don't see any method to apply that. Neither can I find a way to set the FromAddress.

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

As per Salesforce documentation you can not set from address for `MassEmailMessage`. The email address of the logged-in user is inserted in the From Address field of the email header.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm

`SingleEmailMessage` has an optional field called `OrgWideEmailAddressId`. This is an `object ID` to an `OrgWideEmailAddress` object. If `OrgWideEmailAddressId` is set, the `OrgWideEmailAddress.DisplayName` field is used in the email header, instead of the logged-in user's Display Name. The sending email address in the header is also set to the field defined in `OrgWideEmailAddress.Address`.

**What you can do, create a new user with the desired email ID and run the batch job with that user.**

Comment: Thanks. So the best option I am left with is to use replyTo and senderDisplayName, correct?

Comment: I have not tried, you can try and post your own answer based on the findings.